# Split list of emails and numbers, construct dictionary with emails as keys and auto-incremented numeric values

Tags: python

I've been struggling with this assignment for a few days and can't figure out how to write proper pythonic code to replace the values in the lists when there are pipes in the list strings.

- We have 2 variables: `fr` and `d`. `fr` is a list of strings and `d` is a dictionary with email addresses as keys and numbers as values (numbers in string format).
- Write code to replace the email address in each of the strings in the `fr` list with the associated value of that email looked up from the dictionary `d`.

  - If the dictionary does not contain the email found in the list, add a new entry in the dictionary for the email found in the `fr` list. The value for this new email key will be the next highest value number in the dictionary in string format.
- Once the dictionary is populated with this new email key and a new number value, replace that email's occurrence in the `fr` list with the number value.
- Don't manually change `fr` and `d`.

Sample input:

```
fr = [
'7@comp1.COM|4|11|GDSPV',
'7@comp1.COM|16|82|GDSPV',
'13@comp1.COM|12|82|GDSPV',
'26@comp1.COM|19|82|GDSPV'
]

d = {
'7@comp1.COM': '199',
'8@comp4.COM': '200',
'13@comp1.COM': '205'
}
```

The assignment gives what the output should look like, but I'm struggling to get there because of the pipes:

```
Value of fr:
['199|4|11|GDSPV', '199|16|82|GDSPV', '205|12|82|GDSPV', '206|19|82|GDSPV']
Value of d:
{'7@comp1.COM': '199', '8@comp4.COM': '200', '13@comp1.COM': '205', '26@comp1.COM': '206'}
```

This is what the assignment gives you to start off:

```
line_list = []
for line in fr:
```

And this is what I have so far:

```
line_list = []
for line in fr:
    pipes = line.split('|')
    if pipes[0] == '7@comp1.COM':
        pipes[0] = d['7@comp1.COM']
    
    elif pipes[0] == '13@comp1.COM':
        pipes[0] = d['13@comp1.COM']

    elif pipes[0] == '26@comp1.COM':
        pipes[0] = d['26@comp1.COM']
    print(pipes)

    if len(d) < 4:
        d['26@comp1.COM'] = '206'

print("Value of fr: ")
print(fr)
print("Value of d:")
print(d)
```

Which outputs:

```
['199', '4', '11', 'GDSPV']
['199', '16', '82', 'GDSPV']
['205', '12', '82', 'GDSPV']
['206', '19', '82', 'GDSPV']
Value of fr: 
['7@comp1.COM|4|11|GDSPV', '7@comp1.COM|16|82|GDSPV', '13@comp1.COM|12|82|GDSPV', '26@comp1.COM|19|82|GDSPV']
Value of d:
{'7@comp1.COM': '199', '8@comp4.COM': '200', '13@comp1.COM': '205', '26@comp1.COM': '206'}
```

Comment: Any time you see your data in your code, you're doing something wrong.  There's no reason you should be checking for specific data values.  Much of the point in writing code is to automate a process so that it can be performed over and over again on different data sets.  Having to change your code to match the dataset defeats a large part of the purpose. - Rethink your logic so that you don't have to know what the values are.

Comment: Oh okay, so you're referring to when I hard-coded the email values into it, right? That makes sense. Thank you Steve!

Comment: @Steve When you're writing code, before you even begin the actual code, do you start with the comments as a way to understand what the question is asking at each step?

Comment: In more complicated cases, possibly.  More likely, I create the simplest high-level boilerplate, like basic loops, `if` blocks, and functions that don't do anything, and then fill in the details.  This case was simple enough that I could just write it straight through and then add the comments just for your benefit, but that's only because I've written this sort of code possibly hundreds of times.  I don't know what I did back when I was first learning.  That was a lot of years ago.  I'm an old timer.

Comment: As a reusable resource for other users, the title of this question is really misleading. It's a red herring that the difficulty is due to the separator being pipes instead of commas - often there is an issue with pipes in regexes in having to backslash-escape '\|' but that isn't the case here. An accurate title would be *"Split list of emails and numbers, construct dictionary with emails as keys and auto-incremented numeric values"*.

Comment: I'm new to Stack Overflow, so I don't know how to change it, but if I figure it out, I will change that. Thanks for the tip @smci

Answer (score 2):

Here's a complete solution:

```
fr = [
    '7@comp1.COM|4|11|GDSPV',
    '7@comp1.COM|16|82|GDSPV',
    '13@comp1.COM|12|82|GDSPV',
    '26@comp1.COM|19|82|GDSPV'
]

d = {
    '7@comp1.COM': '199',
    '8@comp4.COM': '200',
    '13@comp1.COM': '205'
}

# Figure out the highest key value in the `d` dictionary and set `next_id` to be one greater than that
next_id = -1
for id in d.values():
    if int(id) > next_id:
        next_id = int(id)
next_id += 1

# Create the start of the list we're going to build up
r = []

# For each input in `fr`...
for line in fr:

    # Split the input into elements
    elements = line.split('|')

    # Extract the email address
    email = elements[0]

    # Is this address in `d`?
    if email not in d:
        # No, so add it with the next id as its value
        d[email] = str(next_id)
        next_id += 1

    # Replace the email element with the value for that email from `d`
    elements[0] = d[email]

    # Concatenate the elements back together and put the resulting string in our results list `r`
    r.append('|'.join(elements))

# Print our three structures
print(f"Value of fr: {fr}")
print(f"Value of d: {d}")
print(f"Value of r: {r}")
```

Result:

```
Value of fr: ['7@comp1.COM|4|11|GDSPV', '7@comp1.COM|16|82|GDSPV', '13@comp1.COM|12|82|GDSPV', '26@comp1.COM|19|82|GDSPV']
Value of d: {'7@comp1.COM': '199', '8@comp4.COM': '200', '13@comp1.COM': '205', '26@comp1.COM': '206'}
Value of r: ['199|4|11|GDSPV', '199|16|82|GDSPV', '205|12|82|GDSPV', '206|19|82|GDSPV']
```

Notice that we don't have to know what any of the email addresses are.
We just process whatever we find.  I wasn't sure what "the next highest value number in the dictionary " meant, so maybe what I did to come up with the next value to use in the dictionary needs to be changed if my interpretation of that is incorrect.

Comment: Happy New Year to you  as well! Thank you for including comments at each step, this is very helpful to me as a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're forgetting to join the elements of the list. `"|".join(pipes)` will give you the final string. From there, all you have to do is to append to `line_list` and print it out after the loop. That isn't the way I'd do it, though. I would look abstract it into a function. In particular:

```py
def substitute(string):
    email, *rest = string.split('|')
    number = d[email]
    return '|'.join([number] + rest)

line_list = []
for line in fr:
    line_list.append(substitute(line))
fr = line_list
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `str.partition` is a bit cuter than `str.split` in this case. There's no need to split on all pipes. Doing it this way also avoids having to explicitly join with pipes again afterwards, though you still have to join. `replaced_fr` in this case will be the list containing the replaced, desired output.

```
replaced_fr = []

for line in fr:
    email, *partitions = line.partition("|")
    value = d.get(email, None)
    if value is None:
        value = str(max(map(int, d.values())) + 1)
        d[email] = value
    replaced_line = "".join([value] + partitions)
    replaced_fr.append(replaced_line)
```

Comment: The choice between `partition` and `split` is a minor issue.  I, however, disagree that `partition` should be preferred here.  Two reasons: 1) the code is simpler and more general using `split`, and 2) if you come back later and want to do something with one of the other values in the construct, you then need to rethink and rewrite that bit of code completely.  If you use `split`, like I did, what you do with each of the elements is completely orthogonal to the code that splits the elements apart and puts them back together.  Readability and future-proofing are both gained by using `split`.